# Facebook OAuth 2 - Post to multiple Facebook profiles at the same time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I would like to post to 2 Facebook profiles from an Android app at the same time. As far as I know, **offline access** is no longer available for Facebook OAuth 2, right? How to get an access token for 2 different profiles, if I need to be logged in to get one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting to a user's wall requires a valid access token of that user. So you can save the extended token of the users when user logged-in. You can replace the short-lived token with the long-lived token by making the call-

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
  grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
  client_id={app-id}&
  client_secret={app-secret}&
  fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)